# Emulator not running in Android Studio as I am using an older Gradle JVM

Tags: gradle, jvm

Whenever I run my app the Gradle sync stops and it gives me this error: This project is configured to use an older Gradle JVM that supports up to version 11 but the current AGP requires a Gradle JVM that supports version 17. How do I fix this? (I am using Kotlin as my programming language)

I tried changing the Gradle JDKs location to be the same as the JAVA_HOME, I thought it would fix the problem but it did not and I still had the same error message